# How to update data using one select in other database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two databases and i have one table "TabelaX" in database "Servidor1" with out data and other database "Servidor2" with one table "TabelaY". And i want do one select in table "TabelaY" and with her data do one Update in table "TabelaX" which is in another database. I already made some code but it is not working correctly.

```
 <?php

      $conn= mysqli_connect('localhost','root',null,'Servidor2') or die 
     (mysqli_connect_error());


     if (!$conn) {
       die("Falha de conexao: ". mysqli_connect_error());
      }
        $ID = $_POST['ID'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM TabelaY WHERE ID = $ID";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      mysqli_select_db($conn,"Servidor1");

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $row1 = $row["ID"];
            $row2 = $row["Data"];

         }
         } else {
          echo "0 results";
      }

      $sql = "INSERT INTO Servidor1.TabelaX (ID, Data)
        SELECT ID, Data
        FROM Servidor3.TabelaW
        WHERE ID = $ID;";
      $sql = "UPDATE Servidor1.TabelaX SELECT ID, Data FROM 
           Servidor3.TabelaW SET Data = $row2 WHERE $row1 = $ID;";
             if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "Dados Inseridos";
      } if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
          echo "Dados Atualizados";
      }


       mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result  ..

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your query is trying to do, because you assign to `$sql` twice without ever executing the first query, but if you're asking how to update a row in tableX based on data from tableY, then:

```sql
    UPDATE Servidor1.TabelaX as x, Servidor2.TabelaY as y
       SET x.Data = y.Data
     WHERE x.id = y.id
       AND x.id = $someIdForWhichYouWantToUpdate
```

Also, do not do this:

```php
        $ID = $_POST['ID'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM TabelaY WHERE ID = $ID";
```

Imagine what happens when the user posts `1; DROP DATABASE Servidor1` into the form. This is called SQL injection and your code is full of vulnerabilities to it.